# Box in glossaries

Tags: glossaries, framed

I use the glossaries package for a list of symbols. The entry

```
\newglossaryentry{box}{
name=\ensuremath{\fbox{$A$}},
sort={A},
description={A},
type=symbolslist
}
```

gives the error

```
! Argument of \boxframe has an extra }.
```

This error does not appear when I use `\mbox` instead of `\fbox`. When trying to make a minimal example, this error did not happen, so I suppose that there is something else wrong, but since my class file is rather large, I could not find the problem. Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: I converted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\fbox` breaks in an expandable context. Then `\protect` can help:

```
\newglossaryentry{box}{
  name={\protect\fbox{$A$}},
  sort={A},
  description={A},
  type=symbolslist
}
```

I have removed `\ensuremath`. It serves no purpose, because its argument is a text mode command (`\fbox`).